# Can I reconfigure a live Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it safe to alter application settings (`config.*`) on a Rails application that is already running?

How can I persist the changes, preferably to a database?

**Update**:

I want to allow the administrator to configure things like Action Mailer through an admin control panel, but I'm not sure if Rails will pick up on the changes.

Comment: Are those settings that will change during the runtime of the application or is it just a one time configuration like a account setup?

Comment: They will probably change pretty frequently. Suppose the admin added a few themes, which consist of different CSS files, to the app during runtime in different directories each. Then he'd alter `config.stylesheets_dir` to point to the theme he wants to use. All without having to restart the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach instead of querying DB is to use Environment variables.

This is how you access environment variables:

```
ENV['name']
```

You may define those variables in .bash_rc for example.

Comment: Nice solution to the persistence problem, but can I set Rails's config variables when it is running? Something like `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = params[:perform_deliveries]` in an `update` action in a `SettingsController`.

Comment: @Matheus Moreira: I think you can. For example, I change Capybara's conf in each scenario to change subdomains. I think it is a similar case with mailer. You best shoot is to test it.

Comment: Very well, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Answer does not answer the question.

Comment: @Nerian: Capybara's conf is totally different than Rails configurations. Rails is loaded before *all and any* specs are run. Therefore, changing one Rails config setting in the beginning is going to apply to *all* specs. At this point in time, I do not know that Rails config settings can be changed at runtime; that is what the question is asking.